# Was the character of Nicol based on a real person?

Tags: historical-accuracy, welcome-to-marwen

In *Welcome to Marwen*, Mark Hogancamp meets Nicol. Eventually, he chooses to rename the fictional town of "Marwen" to "Marwencol", named after himself, his rescuer Wendy, and now Nicol.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marwencol), the real Mark Hogancamp did call his model town "Marwencol", but it was a combination of the names "Mark, "Wendy", and "Colleen". Does that mean that Nicol was a fictional character created for the movie?

Was the character of Nicol based on a real person?